# How do I describe a directory structure in JSON as a C# type

Tags: c#, json, typescript, serialization, types

I have the following directory structure:

```
v1
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    common
        common.txt
```

I want to create a C# function that crawls this directory structure and returns a data type that I can serialize to JSON. The JSON would look something like this:

```json
{
    "v1": [
        "file1.txt",
        "file2.txt",
        {
            "common": [
                "common.txt"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

where the keys are folders and the values are arrays of files in those folders.

Currently I have a function that looks like this:

```cs
private static Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string?>> Get(string baseDirectory, string version) =>
    Directory.GetDirectories($"{baseDirectory}\\{version}")
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Name = x,
            Files = Directory.GetFiles(x).Select(Path.GetFileName),
        })
        .ToDictionary(o => Path.GetRelativePath(version, o.Name), o => o.Files);
```

It allows me to traverse the directory one level deep but the Dictionary cannot express nested directories.

As a side note, I usually like to use TypeScript to prototype types. I came up with the following type definition in TypeScript that uses a union type to describe the nesting:

```
type DirectoryStructure<K extends string, V> = {
  [P in K]: (V | DirectoryStructure<K, V>)[]
};
```

I'm not sure if this is helpful, as I don't think C# has an equivalent to union types in C#.

So in short I'm looking for a type in C# that can describe a directory structure and that is easily serializable to JSON. Something like a Dictionary but with nesting basically. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pls show us the code you have done so far. How do you create a list of folders for example?

Comment: @Serge I have provided the implementation of my current function. It's a slight modification of the code found [here](https://anthonygiretti.com/2020/07/06/exposing-proto-files-in-a-grpc-service-over-a-frameworkless-and-lightweight-api/).

Comment: What is your problem here?  1) Deserializing the JSON shown to some appropriate c# model?  2) Traversing a directory hierarchy and creating that same appropriate c# data model by making repeated calls to `Directory.GetDirectories()` and `Directory.GetFiles(x)`?

Comment: The second one yes. I'm trying to create a C# model that can represent more than one directory level. Right now `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string?>>` can only represent a directory that is one level deep.

Comment: Does the JSON have to look like that?  Or is your format flexible?

Comment: @dbc Preferably it should resemble a directory structure. This is the simplest JSON form I could come up with that did.

Answer (score -1):

```
var structure = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

is all you need.